# If the magnetic force observed is $q \vec{v }\times \vec{B}$ then how do stationary magnets attract each other?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, magnetic-moment

My theory is that it is because of random motion of electrons of atoms inside the magnet but if it truly random then all forces must cancel out also is the force really enough to attract huge magnets.

Comment: Electrons do not exhibit "random" motion.  They can have well defined spin and orbital angular momentum.

Comment: This question does not show any research effort.  See, for example [Force between magnets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force_between_magnets):  *The forces of attraction field of magnets are due to microscopic currents of electrically charged electrons orbiting nuclei and the intrinsic magnetism of fundamental particles (such as electrons) that make up the material*

Answer (score 1):

The equation $F=q\vec{v}\times \vec{B}$ only describes the force on a moving electrically charged particle in a magnetic field. It does not work for magnetic forces on other magnets.

If you want to calculate the force between magnets, it helps to think of them as [dipoles of magnetic charge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_dipole)--that is, a positive (north) and a negative (south) charge bound together with a small separation between them. Similarly to electric charges, like repels like and opposites attract, with the force going as the inverse square of the distance. So, two dipoles near each other will want to rotate so that opposite poles are close to each other and then will attract each other.

Now, magnetic charges probably don't exist, but it's a simple model that works well. Actual magnetic fields are generated by loops of electric current, the intrinsic angular momentum of elementary particles, or by their bound state orbitals.